# How to update array field value with 'append' function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

In the database, I have an array field `is_deleted` with serialize  function in the model. I want to append the array values in the database field. Here is the function used in postgresql.

```
Message.update_all(['is_deleted = array_append(is_deleted, ?)', 2])
```

How can it be done with the sqllite database?

Answer (score 2):

you need to `serialize` column in model

```
Class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :is_deleted, Array
end
```

for a side note if you want a column to be used to store array then its should be column_type string or `text`

```
Message.all.each { |m| m.update_attribute(:is_deleted, m.is_deleted.push(2)) }
```

Comment: I have already done that in the model.What i want to do is want to update all the record with single query and append the new array values in the field with the existing values.Like the postgres example i have provided in the question.

Comment: i have changed the answer , please have a look.

Comment: This is one of the good solution. But can it possible to do it with a single query like the above postgres sql query.becuase i have more then 1000 record and it's not feasible for 1000 queries.

Comment: yep, i agree with you, its bad solution for big record, but for now  it can help your roadblock, i'll update answer incase if i find feasible solution. thanks.